# LINQ select one bool from condition over multiple rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have data series, in which every member contains some elements and every element has float variable D representing date in OADate (excel format). I need to find out, if ANY of the series intersects with "neighbours". So result is one bool.
Is there any way to do this in LINQ ?
This is my current working code

```
         bool overlaps = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < series.Count-1; i++) {
            if (series[i].elements.Last().D > series[i + 1].elements.First().D) {
                overlaps = true;
                break;
            }           
        }
```

thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
series.Skip(1)
      .Where((s,i) => series[i].elements.Last().D > s.elements.First().D).Any();
```

Explanation: thus we skipped first element, then `series[i]` actually will be same as `series[i]` in your sample, and `s` will be item at index `series[i+1]`.

Comment: @MSakherSawan yep, there are overloads for Select, Where, SkipWhile and TakeWhile operators which have index parameter

Comment: I got it immediately, and needed it tens of times!

Answer (score 1):

```
series.Zip(series.Skip(1).Concat(series.Take(1)), (a, b) => 
        new { a = a, b = b })
       .Any(c=>c.a.elements.Last().D > c.b.elements.First().D);
```

Zipping `series` with itself rounded by one, and then comparing the item of the main `series` with the corresponding one of the rotated one!